# elasticsearch couchbase-transport plugin not listening

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, couchbase

I have some Couchbase servers, and I have a dedicated Elasticsearch server with the couchbase-transport plugin.

My Elasticsearch settings :

```
network.publish_host: 192.X.X.X
network.host: 192.X.X.X
```

`netstat -laputen | grep 9300`  :

```
192.X.X.X:9300
```

My Elasticsearch service is listening correctly on the IP, but when I use `netstat` for the port of the couchbase-transport plugin :

```
netstat -laputen | grep 9091
```

The plugin is listening on `127.0.0.1`,  and then I can't reach the plugin with the Couchbase replication service..

Do you know how I could change this listening IP ?

Comment: Elastic search is being used 9200 port by default. Did you change the port number for ES to 9300?

Comment: Elasticsearch listens to 9200 AND 9300 ports in my case.  Maybe because this server is used for Couchbase and Kibana-logstash (log server).

Comment: In your config/elasticsearch.yml, Did you add below lines? couchbase.port=9091, couchbase.username="username", couchbase.password="pwd", couchbase.num_vbuckets="1024", couchbase.defaultDocumentType="couchbaseDocument", couchbase.checkpointDocumentType="couchbaseCheckpoint"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could well be a bug. Please open an issue here https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/issues and I'll take a look.

Comment: I reported the bug,  but this is my workaround : comment all lines which specify the address in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` ,  and the both are binding to  `*:port`